# Firestore says users is not part of the list in the rules, but it is

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to read a collection via `onSnapshot` from my **firebase emulator** (added this in case it makes a difference)

Here are my firebase rules:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {


    // Rules for specific collections
    match /users/{userId}/organizations/{docId} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && resource.data.users != null && (request.auth.token.email in resource.data.users);
      allow write: if false;
    }

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if (request.auth != null) && resource.data.users != null && (request.auth.token.email in resource.data.users);
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error

> Property users is undefined on object. for 'list' @ L9, Property users is undefined on object. for 'list' @ L14

which results in `permission-denied`

L9 and L14 are the `allow read` lines. I assume it's the `request.auth.token.email in resource.data.users` statement that's an issue. However, I do have `users` as an `array` in each document.

The rationale for this is that the organization has an owner (the user who owns that document and other shared users)

I tried running this through GPT a few times but can't figure out the error here.

**edit**

Error causing code:

```
snapshot => {
  let items = <any>[];
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log('docData')
    console.log(doc.data())
    items.push(doc.data())
  })
  debugItems.value = items
},
```

When I change the permissions to `allow read: if true;` I get all documents back from my collection which include the `users` field.

Comment: The error on line 14 is for the `match /{document=**}`, so with a recursive wildcard. Can you show the pinpoint the error message to when you're reading a single document, and if so, can you show code that is causing the error, and the document that this reads?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @FrankvanPuffelen, It is an error for L9 and L14. However, when I changed the condition to `allow read: if true;` it returns the document with the users field. I have added detail to the post.